# Can I override default read() method in io.BufferedReader?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to send only part of the file into STDIN of another process?

```
#Python 3.5
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen, STDOUT

fh = io.open("test0.dat", "rb")
fh.seek(10000)
p = Popen(command, stdin=fh, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
p.wait()
```

How do I make sure that `command` will only read 1000 more bytes from stdin and then encounters EOF.
I have no control over how command reads standard input.

Comment: my answer was incorrect. problem is `Popen` uses real OS handles, so it's not possible to fool it like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is, when passed an handle, Popen tries to get `fileno`, and uses real OS handles, so it's not possible to fool it easily with other file-like objects.

But you can set `Popen` `stdin` as `PIPE`, write only the correct number of bytes to it, possibly in small chunks, at the rythm you choose, and close it afterwards

```
import io
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen, STDOUT

fh = io.open("test0.dat", "rb")
fh.seek(10000)


p = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
p.stdin.write(fh.read(1000))
# do something & write again
p.stdin.write(fh.read(1000))
# now it's enough: close the input
p.stdin.close()

p.wait()
```

Be careful though: since `stdin` and `stdout` use `PIPE`, you have to consume `stdout` to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: edited my answer. And you can read by small chunks. The difference with the big file is that you can decide when to close the pipe.

Comment: great, thank you! Do you know which method Popen calls after fileno()? I figured the override but nothing like read/readline/readlines seem to be called.

Comment: I think it ends up using `os.read()` after having got hold of the file descriptor: extract: `data = os.read(fd, 4096)` (not sure, the module is horribly complex). I'm glad to have dug up a solution. I had to open some low-level module that I developed a long time ago for this (my need was to pass "yes" continuously to a process)